# Iterate over Mongo DBCursor in Play Framework Template

Tags: scala, mongodb, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am trying to iterate over a mongo DBCursor in a play framework 2.0.1 view. However, nothing is listed. Ideally I want to paginate the cursor, but even if I am able to list all objects in the cursor it will be fine.

Here is what I am doing.
In my controller I query the Mongo DB and render the DBCursor. The logs state that the cursor is not empty.

Then in the view I have the following:

```
@(cursor: com.mongodb.DBCursor)


@main("Title") {
<div id="objects" class="content">
 <h2>Objects</h2>

 @if(cursor.count() == 0) {
    There are currently no objects in the data base.
 } else {
    @while(cursor.hasNext()) {
        @cursor.next().get("name");
    }
 } 
</div>    
}
```

Unfortunately, nothing is listed, besides the heading when the page is rendered.
Funny enough, if I omit the `@while(cursor.hasNext())` and output only the first object from the cursor, then it is rendered on the page.

Apparently something is wrong with that while. So, is it possible to render (and/or paginate) the DBCursor in the view?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know why the @while() doesn't work. Maybe it simply doesn't exists in scala templates? But I can tell you, that this kind of work is not intended to be done in the view. The view is for rendering, while the controller is for logic and accessing the database. Consider to parse the DBObjects to a list or array in the controller, and use @for to iterate over it in the view.

Comment: oh, that's embarrassing. I thought there is a while. So what you are saying is, I should fetch the objects from the cursor in the controller and then just pass them in a list to the view. Is it possible to somehow paginate them? They can be a lot. and there is really no need to fetch them all at once. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: you can paginate by using the limit() and skip() methods. Example:  myCollection.find(query).skip(40).limit(20);

Comment: thanks, that should work. if you write that as an answer, I will accept it. Due to the bad design (accessing mongo in the view) I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe @while doesn't exists in scala templates!?

This kind of work is not intended to be done in the view. The view is for rendering, while the controller is for logic and accessing the database. Consider to parse the DBObjects to a list or array in the controller, and use @for to iterate over it in the view.

For pagination use something like this:

```
myCollection.find(query).skip(40).limit(20);
```

Comment: I was looking how to do this too. Converting cursor to a list and then iterating over a list is so inefficient it's almost insane to even consider doing this.